# Twilio 11200 HTTP retrieval failure with Node app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, twilio

My Node.js app is set to respond to a text message received at a paid Twilio number. I tested it using ngrok and everything worked fine. Once I deployed the app to Heroku, however, I started seeing an 11200 HTTP retrieval failure error in the Twilio console.

Are there configuration settings in Heroku that I need to set up?

```
// Twilio Credentials
const accountSid = 'xxx';
const authToken = 'xxx';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();   
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use('/', function(request, response){
response.send();
});

app.post('/sms', function(req, res) {

const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

twiml.message('Hi, this is Culpability. Your incident has been logged. Your 
unique id # XXXX');

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
res.end(twiml.toString());

});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
// console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Did you update the URL for your phone to the Heroku URL? Have you tested that you can reach the Heroku URL using `curl` for example?

Comment: Checked the URL and will try curl but I have verified the Heroku URL is reachable other ways!

Comment: Could you share the URL for your application with me over email and I'll see what I can find out? The email address is philnash@twilio.com

Comment: Yes, sending now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the problem is mostly in the method you are using to send the response. Currently your final line of the `/sms` route is `res.end(twiml.toString());` however [`Response#end` is used "to quickly end the response without any data."](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end)

I think your use of `res.writeHead()` might be outdated now too.

I would change your `/sms` route to something like this:

```
app.post('/sms', function(req, res) {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message('Hi, this is Culpability. Your incident has been logged. Your unique id # XXXX');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.status(200).send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Then try redeploying to Heroku and see what happens.